# Add another Apache web root

Tags: php, apache, apache-config

I have a PHP project into a local directory (`/home/user/myproject`) outside `/var/www/html` (I'm using Apache2 within Ubuntu). To add that directory as another web root I added:

```
  Alias /myproject /home/user/myproject
  <Directory /project>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

into the apache2.conf file and restarted the server. However, when I try to access the project from the browser with `localhost/project` I get the 403 Forbidden error. 
Am I missing something with the apache configuration?

Comment: For a start home directories are often 700, i.e. the owner is the only one with permissions to read / write / execute. So chances are, the user you're running apache as, doesn't have permissions.

Comment: I forgot to write that I ran chown -R www-data:www-data on the directory

Comment: On the `myproject` directory? The apache user needs at least read all the way along the tree. So, /home, /home/user as well as /home/user/myproject.

Comment: You're right, thanks, but would you suggest to do that all the way along the /home tree?

Comment: No, I'd suggest you be more specific about what permissions you allow (i.e. don't just chown /home), perhaps using a new group with relevant users in. Or, don't put the files in your home directory, which seems more sensible to me.